# How to reference a script when colliding in Unity

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine

Im trying to reference a script when colliding with other gameObject. In this case there are different scripts for different enemies so I need that if the player touch a Default enemy, it takes X damage but when touching Default_2, Y damage.

The point is that the player gameObject look for the Enemy script inside the enemy gameObject and if it touches another then another. (The enemy gameObject also have an EnemyBehaviour script so I need to locate the EnemyClass script not the Behaviour)

I dont know how to look for a script inside a gameObject if I need to search for others too

Comment: Unity uses a [component based model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component-based_software_engineering) where things in the gameworld have a list of specialised components on them. Consider making some kind of ContactDamage script which does just one thing: causes x damage when a collision occurs. This script can exist alongside your existing ones and can be used & configured by prefabs. This is just one way to design such a thing though: inheritance and interfaces are also equally valid.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the amount of damage an enemy does is a public variable

You also want to check if it's an enemy you're touching, so give all of your enemies an "enemy" tag.

Also make sure the function used to damage the player takes in a float

Your code should look something like this

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
     if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
     {
          float damage = collision.getComponent<(put your enemy script here)>().damage;
          TakeDamage(damage);
     }
 }
```

I think this should work let me know if it doesn't

Comment: Use `CompareTag()` instead of `==` or `Equals()` with object tags.